# IP Rating for Recessed Shower Lighting

Tags: lighting, shower, waterproofing

I've heard the terms "damp" and "wet" used in referring to lighting fixture ratings, but the fixture I am looking at has a specific IP rating. Is there an IP rating equivalent to the "damp" and "wet" ratings? The fixture I am looking at is a recessed, GU10 fixture with an IP44 rating.

Also, I do understand the IP rating system. For a fixture I intend to place in a rain shower, I should only need an IPX2 rating since condensation would be the method on ingress.

Comment: Do an end-run around the entire issue by using 12V LED lighting.    Can't get electrocuted if there isn't any high voltage in the shower.

Comment: That wasn't my concern. My concern was the potential for arcing and damage to the fixture. Also, wouldn't a 12V electrical system (powered by a wall wart) still need to adhere to any regulations?

Answer (score 1):

NEC 410.10.D The last sentence states marked for wet locations were subject to shower spray. I believe this is interpreted as any area inside the rim of the shower to be a wet location. I know IP54 = NEMA13 provides protection from water spray. None of the NEMA to IP cross references I have have a 4 for the first digit so I am not sure on IP44.

Comment: The first digit only matters for dry ingress (i.e. Dust). IP44 should provide similar waterproofing to IP54, so if NEMA13, or IP54, adheres to code for wet locations, IP44 would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This chart should help it lists the categories! The number is made up jointly from a left handed solid IP rating and a right hand water IP rating

[image]

Comment: I understand IP ratings. I want to know how it relates to "wet" and "damp" ratings.

Answer (score -2):

I'd go with led and buy best IP/wet rated you can find, if in doubt silicone connections to reduce chances of arc, corrosion issues

Comment: My question is about how the bathroom "wet" and "damp" ratings relate to IP ratings, if at all.